# Not able to show exact time I updated site

Tags: javascript, datetime

So, I'm making a website that archives all of Magnus Scheving's interviews, but most of the interviews are from before 2019. So  I put this Javascript code on all pages to tell everyone that I'm updating it regularly and finding new interviews -

```js
//
// format date as dd-mmm-yy
// example: 12-Jan-99
//
function date_ddmmmyy(date)
{
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = date.getYear();

  // handle different year values 
  // returned by IE and NS in 
  // the year 2000.
  if(y >= 2000)
  {
    y -= 2000;
  }
  if(y >= 100)
  {
    y -= 100;
  }

  // could use splitString() here 
  // but the following method is 
  // more compatible
  var mmm = 
    ( 1==m)?'Jan':( 2==m)?'Feb':(3==m)?'Mar':
    ( 4==m)?'Apr':( 5==m)?'May':(6==m)?'Jun':
    ( 7==m)?'Jul':( 8==m)?'Aug':(9==m)?'Sep':
    (10==m)?'Oct':(11==m)?'Nov':'Dec';

  return "" +
    (d<10?"0"+d:d) + "-" +
    mmm + "-" +
    (y<10?"0"+y:y);
}


//
// get last modified date of the 
// current document.
//
function date_lastmodified()
{
  var lmd = document.lastModified;
  var s   = "Unknown";
  var d1;

  // check if we have a valid date
  // before proceeding
  if(0 != (d1=Date.parse(lmd)))
  {
    s = "" + date_ddmmmyy(new Date(d1));
  }

  return s;
}

//
// finally display the last modified date
// as DD-MMM-YY
//
document.write( 
  "This page was updated on " + 
  date_lastmodified() );
```

I'd be happy with it, but the thing is, it only shows the date you've updated it and not the time. Is there any way to add the time? I'd prefer it in AEST time, thanks.

I searched the web for any answers, but they all gave me answers on how to put the 'last updated DATE' and not time inside an HTML page

Comment: None of the solutions have worked ):

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_current_time()
    {
      var currentTime = new Date();

//You can convert passed time into Date() format first if you are recieving as parameter

      var hours = currentTime.getHours();
      var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
      var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
      }
      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
      }
    
      var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
      return timeString;
    }
```

Then display the last modified date and time as DD-MMM-YY HH:MM

```
document.write( 
  "This page was updated on " + 
  date_lastmodified() + " at " + 
  get_current_time());
```

You can use some library to convert into timezones

---

```js
function date_ddmmmyy(date) {
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = date.getYear();

  // handle different year values 
  // returned by IE and NS in 
  // the year 2000.
  if (y >= 2000) {
    y -= 2000;
  }
  if (y >= 100) {
    y -= 100;
  }

  // could use splitString() here 
  // but the following method is 
  // more compatible
  var mmm =
    (1 == m) ? 'Jan' : (2 == m) ? 'Feb' : (3 == m) ? 'Mar' :
    (4 == m) ? 'Apr' : (5 == m) ? 'May' : (6 == m) ? 'Jun' :
    (7 == m) ? 'Jul' : (8 == m) ? 'Aug' : (9 == m) ? 'Sep' :
    (10 == m) ? 'Oct' : (11 == m) ? 'Nov' : 'Dec';

  return "" +
    (d < 10 ? "0" + d : d) + "-" +
    mmm + "-" +
    (y < 10 ? "0" + y : y);
}


//
// get last modified date of the 
// current document.
//
function date_lastmodified() {
  var lmd = document.lastModified;
  var s = "Unknown";
  var d1;

  // check if we have a valid date
  // before proceeding
  if (0 != (d1 = Date.parse(lmd))) {
    s = "" + date_ddmmmyy(new Date(d1));
  }

  return s;
}

//
// finally display the last modified date
// as DD-MMM-YY

// -->

function get_current_time() {
  var currentTime = new Date();

  //You can convert passed time into Date() format first if you are recieving as parameter

  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  return timeString;
}

//
document.write(
  "This page was updated on " +
  date_lastmodified(), ' ', get_current_time());
```

Comment: Does not work. It doesn't show anything.

Comment: Why? Do you get any error? Can you console.log() to find root cause?

Comment: No, I don't get an error. The code just doesn't show anything... not sure what console.log is. I'm new to HTML and Java.

Comment: I thought I have missed something. Hence I have tested it out. it works perfectly fine. console.log is something we used for testing by priting variables and information as per our business login refer [link](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_console_log.asp) here

Comment: I have updated the code. but I haven't converted the time zone

I got result like _This page was updated on 04-Dec-23 16:17:48_